# Using Do Loop whilst omitting cells based on a separate selection

Tags: excel, vba, loops, do-loops, reliability

I am currently working on a reliability calculator and as part of a wider calculation, the following loop is required:

```
'Add redundant units to any pieces of equipment with reliabilites lower than target
'Set Variables
    DatRange = Worksheets(system).ListObjects("Table_" & system).ListColumns("Reliability of Configuration").DataBodyRange
    minVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(DatRange)
    Do Until minVal > Target_Reliability

    'Identify row of min value
        Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(minVal, DatRange, 0)

    'Add redundancy to relevant row
        quantity_fitted = Worksheets(system).ListObjects("Table_" & system).ListColumns("Quantity Fitted (n)").DataBodyRange(Row)
        Worksheets(system).ListObjects("Table_" & system).ListColumns("Quantity Fitted (n)").DataBodyRange(Row) = quantity_fitted + 1

    'Prime for next loop
        DatRange = Worksheets(system).ListObjects("Table_" & system).ListColumns("Reliability of Configuration").DataBodyRange
        minVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(DatRange)

    Loop
```

So each line/row of components is checked, by inspecting the reliability value stated in their "Reliability of Configuration" column, to find whichever line/row offers the lowest reliability. Then additional quantities are added to that line until it's reliability exceeds the target reliability of the system, which is set by the user separately.

This works in principle, except within another column I have a drop down selection for the user to input whether a particular component is arranged within a "Standby", "Active, or "Series" configuration.

What I need is the code above to run, but to omit any line/row in which the "Configuration:" column value is set to "Series".

In other words, is there a way to edit this part of the code:

```
'Set Variables
    DatRange = Worksheets(system).ListObjects("Table_" & system).ListColumns("Reliability of Configuration").DataBodyRange
    minVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(DatRange)
    Do Until minVal > Target_Reliability
```

So that instead of simply finding the minimum value, it finds the minimum value of any line which is also set to either "Active" or "Standby", ignoring any value of which the line is set to "Series"?

I hope this makes sense. I've been struggling with this for a while and really need help.

Thank you!

Comment: There's a MINIFS formula.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can incorporate that into VBA code?

Comment: Yes, in the same way as you used min.

Comment: Could you not just filter your sheet and then run the above code?

Comment: @Zac unfortunately this is not an option as this tool is designed to be a "plug and play" feature for the end user